# Show specific form-fields at specific places in the HTML template (Django)

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have a form with three fields `field1,field2,field3` - in my template I want to show those fields at specific places, and not together. At best `field1, field2` are "shown together" and then a bit further down, I need `field3` to be shown.

My HTML is right now

```html
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="add-link-wrapper">

  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
    Add product
  </legend>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}

    <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

but {{form}} shows all three fields - I would like to have it a bit like

```html
<div class="content-section">
  <div class="add-link-wrapper">

  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
    Tilføj produkt til tracking
  </legend>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.field1 and form.field2 |crispy}}  <!-- Show field1 and field 2 here -->

    <div class="form-group">
      
    </div>
  </form>
some more html code
</div>
{{form.field3|crispy}} <!-- Show field3 here -->
<button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [crispy's](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_templatetags.html#templatetags.crispy_forms_filters.as_crispy_field) `as_crispy_field` to achieve that. This also means you will display each field individually by yourself and not the usual looping through the form by the Django template. Your code should look like this

```
  <div class="content-section">
    <div class="add-link-wrapper">
      <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
        Tilføj produkt til tracking
      </legend>
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Show field1 and field 2 here -->
        <div class="form-group">
          {{form.field1|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          {{form.field2|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
          <span>some more html code</span>

        <!-- Show field3 here -->
        <div class="form-group">
          {{form.field3|as_crispy_field}}
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```